# JAVA Android studio Doesn't send data to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to send data to my Realtime Database when i create new account. Creating new account i will see that in Authentication it has added new account but in my Realtime Database it hasn't added anything.

When debugging i see that in console `Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Continue...");` doesn't show up and anything past that.

I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPYqEpbihCs&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE9XqkckEJJA0I1wVKbUAOdv&index=28

Database structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3YxJ.png)

RegisterActivity.java
Code that sends data to Firebase database

```
private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth.");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Continue...");
                        //1st check: Make sure the username is not already in use
                        if(firebaseMethods.checkIfUsernameExists(username, 
                        dataSnapshot)){
                            append = myRef.push().getKey().substring(3,10);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: username already exists.    
                            Appending random string to name: " + append);
                        }
                        username = username + append;

                        //add new user to the database
                        firebaseMethods.addNewUser(email, username, "", "", "");

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Signup successful. Sending 
                        verification email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: Cancelled ");
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read    
                        value.",databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });

            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
}
```

I use another file where i store all my FirebaseMethod logic

```
package com.example.searchapp.Utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.example.searchapp.R;
import com.example.searchapp.login.RegisterActivity;
import com.example.searchapp.models.User;
import com.example.searchapp.models.UserAccountSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.EmailAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class FirebaseMethods {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMethods";

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private String userID;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    private Context mContext;

    public FirebaseMethods(Context context){
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mContext = context;
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();


        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        }
    }
    public boolean checkIfUsernameExists(String username, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: check if " + username + "already exists");
        User user = new User();
//dataSnapshot.child(userID).getChildren()
        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users)).getChildren()){
            Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: datasnapshot " + ds);

            user.setUsername(ds.getValue(User.class).getUsername());
            Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: username "+user.getUsername());

            if(StringManipulation.expandUsername(user.getUsername()).equals(username)){
                Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: FOUND A MATCH "+ user.getUsername());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    public void registerNewEmail(final String email, String password, final String username){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: createUserWithEmail " + task.isSuccessful());

                        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.auth_failed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Authstate changed " +userID );
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    public void addNewUser(String email, String username,String description,String website,String profile_photo){

        User user = new User(userID,1,email,StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username));

        myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                .child(userID)
                .setValue(user);

        UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings(
                description,
                username,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                profile_photo,
                username,
                website
        );
        myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
                .child(userID)
                .setValue(settings);
    }

}
```

Strings file

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">SearchApp</string>
    <string name="edit_profile">Edit Profile</string>
    <string name="sign_out">Sign Out</string>
    <string name="auth_failed">Failed to Authenticate</string>
    <string name="auth_success">Authenticate Success</string>
    <string name="dbname_users">users</string>
    <string name="dbname_user_account_settings">user_account_settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not attaching `mAuthListener` to Firebase anywhere, which means that Firebase never calls it.

You'll need to call `addAuthStateListener` to make Firebase aware of your listener, with something like:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
```